# How to remove all break tags from a string in PHP?

Tags: php, regex, string

Seems simple enough but I'm having some issues, I tried using preg_replace:

```
preg_replace("<br />", "", $string);
```

But what I get is this `<>` in place of the `<br />` in the string when outputted. The break tags in the string will always be in this format not in any of these:

```
<br/>
<br>
<BR />
etc.
```

so what's the error I'm making?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
preg_replace("#<br />#", "", $string);
```

You needed a delimiter character.  `#` works fine here, since it's not used in the regex.

Comment: people dont always close their breaks like they should so it should probably be something like `#<br[\s/]?>#`.

Comment: +1 The delimiters for strings is probably one of the most commonly unknown things in the language.

Answer (score 7):

In addition to what [Matthew Flaschen said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3182912/how-to-remove-all-break-tags-from-a-string-in-php/3182917#3182917), you could probably get away with simply `str_replace()` as you are not using any of a regex's *power* there.

Alternatively you could match different types of `<br />` like so (using a regex this time)...

```
#<br\s?/?>#
```

This will match `<br/>`, `<br>`, `<br />`. Add the `i` flag to make it match in a case insensitive manner (or use `str_ireplace()` if not using the regex).

Also, if you are doing any more HTML manipulation than this, consider a [parser](http://htmlpurifier.org/).